# Extract title from a file in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a `php code` in which I want to extract a `title` from a file in `php`.

```
$good_title = ExtractGoodTitle("good/web/gooddump/GOOD_2.html");  // Line A


function ExtractGoodTitle($filename)
{

.
.
.
.
    return $title;
}
```

The function `ExtractGoodTitle($filename)` extracts a title from the file `GOOD_2.html` I haven't included code in the function as my question is related to `Line A`. In the `gooddump` directory, following files are present:

1. GOOD_2.html
2. GOOD_3.html
3. GOOD_4.html

   .
   .
   .
   .
4. GOOD_740.html

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need make at Line A as `GOOD_2.html` file may or may not be present in the `gooddump` directory. Looking for a dynamic solution.

Comment: use [`file_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) built-in function. Please include your function's code.

Comment: Why fill/pad out the question and title with a question your not actually asking, search for what you asking about and your find many solutions [*check file exists in php*](https://www.google.com/search?q=check+file+exists+in+php&oq=check+file+exists+in+php)